# Is there a way to disable `user-select: none` in react-pdf?

Tags: react-pdf

I would like to allow users to copy and paste text from PDF documents. However when I inspect the page (with Chrome dev tools) where we are rendering the PDF document, I notice there are styles that set `user-select` to `none`. I can't find anything in the react-pdf documentation that indicates how to allow users to select text. Hoping someone knows how!

Here are the CSS rules that are defined on `.react-pdf__Document > div > div > div`. We could certainly override it with `!important` but I'm hoping there's another way.

```
{
    position: absolute;
    inset: 10px 20px;
    height: 1229.41px;
    width: 950px;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manually add `user-select: none` to the following class:

```
.react-pdf__Page__textContent
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

The browser is responsible for handling user choices thus the user interface allows the user to copy print / read aloud or otherwise interact with the text transferred download either when using a real PDF download/renderer or in react-pdf cases a web reproduction of a PDF.js.

If you serve "Image Only" as PDF then the browser needs to use any OCR screen reader.

[image]